# Is there a way to trigger Jenkins parameterized jobs by sending JSON for the params - without using a query param string?

Tags: jenkins

I am using python to trigger a Jenkins job.  Right now I'm using python `requests` lib; I trigger the job directly as:

```
response = requests.post("https://jenkinsurl/job/myJob/buildWithParameters", auth=(user, password), verify=False)
```

I need to send build parameters to the job.  All tutorials I see, indicate to send the paramaters as a query string on the job URL (example - if I wanted to send params 'param1' with 'val1' and 'param2' with 'val2', I'd post as follows:)

```
response = requests.post("https://jenkinsurl/job/myJob/buildWithParameters?param1=val1&param2=val2", auth=(user, password), verify=False)
```

The problem is that I need to send sensitive params, which I can't supply in plaintext as part of an URL.  **Is there a way to send the params as part of the post body?  I can't seem to find the syntax/structure the json would need be in, to accomplish this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by passing the params directly to the 'data' option in requests.

So in the example above (to send params 'param1' with value 'val1' and 'param2' with value 'val2' to the Jenkins job, this worked:)

```
var jobParams = {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2'}
response = requests.post("https://jenkinsurl/job/myJob/buildWithParameters, data=jobParams, auth=(user, password), verify=False)
```

EDIT: If you are facing this issue, make sure not to solve it by sending the params to requests' 'params' arg - it will work (trigger the job with the params) but all it's doing is generating the query string for you - those param/values would still get tacked on the URL